# Get an element of navbar to center

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a navbar like below. How do I center the element `Help Video`.

```css
  .header_title{
      font-size: 20px;
      color: white;
  }

  .center {
      text-align:center;
  }
  
  .center {
      float:none;
      display:inline-block;
      *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
      *zoom:1; /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */
      vertical-align: top;
    }
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar_form" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><font class="header_title" >Some text</font></a>
      </div>
    
     
      <!-- Fixed navbar I want to center this.--> 
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse center">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><font class="header_title" >HELP VIDEO</font></a>  
        </div>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

But it is not coming to center. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share a fiddle?

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/NyvCIsZaF1 @GaneshSalunkhe

Comment: give Margin : 10px 43% to "HELP VIDEO" Anchor (a) element.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below styles from your stylesheet.

```
.center {
float:none;
display:inline-block;
*display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
*zoom:1; /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `display: block !important;` 
 from  `.navbar-collapse.collapse {` 
 and give `text-align:center;`  
 to `.navbar {`.

It will center Help Video part.

You can check your updated code [Here.](http://www.bootply.com/dXjRdZAQHE)

Answer (score 0):

Run the code snippet, You can see that element HELP VIDEO is aligned to the center.

```css
.header_title{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
}
.center {
    text-align:center;
}
/*
Remove these styles

.center {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; 
    *zoom:1; 
    vertical-align: top;
} 
*/
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar_form" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><font class="header_title" >Some text</font></a>
  </div>


  <!-- Fixed navbar I want to center this.--> 
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse center">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><font class="header_title" >HELP VIDEO</font></a>  
    </div>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```